# Разбиение текста на абзацы

Tags: php, массивы, строки

Всем привет.

Решение где-то на виду, но я его не вижу.

Суть вопроса: есть текст, несколько К символов. Обычный текст, с разделительными знаками, в общем статья. Нужно разбить этот текст на куски по 1000 символов и до следующей точки, то есть разбить статью на абзацы, но чтобы не было разрыва в средине предложения.

Как я начал делать: сначала разбил весь текст на предложения, потом в цикле думал сделать объединение этих предложений в блоки по 1к символов. Но вот застопорился на коде. Как правильно сделать нумерацию получившихся блоков?

```
$pred = explode('.', $str); /// разбиваю текст на предложение
$pz   = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < count($pred); $i++) { /// по очереди считываю каждое предложение

    while ($pz < 1000) { /// проверяю длину блока, и выполняю цыкл до тех пор пока длина меньше 1000 символов
        $lench   = strlen($pred[$i]); //определяю длину предложения
        $pz      = $pz + $lench; /// добавляю это число к длине блока
        $abz[$l] = $abz[$l] . $pred[$i]; ///добавляю к блоку предложение
    }
}
```

Как правильно задать переменную $l ?

Может я не туда копаю, может кто знает способ попроще? Буду рад помощи. В итоге должны получится несколько блоков (массив строк) с длиной примерно 1000 символов, и они должны заканчиваться точкой.

P.S.: нашол готовый класс от Яндекса, который делает то- что мне нужно... но как его использовать... ума не приложу

```
<?php
abstract class Big_Text_Translate {
    /**
     * @var int - максимальное число символов для отправки переводчику
     */
    public static $symbolLimit = 1000;

    /**
     * @var string- символы, по которым текст делится на предложения
     */
    public static $sentensesDelimiter = '.';

    /**
     * @static
     * @param  $text - исходный текст для разбиения на предложения
     * @return array - массив предложений, еще не окончательный
     */
    protected static function toSentenses ($text) {
        $sentArray = explode(self::$sentensesDelimiter, $text);
        return $sentArray;
    }

    /**
     * Разделение текста на массив больших кусков
     * @param  string $text - большой текстовый фрагмент, требующий разделения на куски
     * @return  array - массив элементов, каждый из которых не превышает предельного числа символов
     */

    public static function toBigPieces ($text) {
        $sentArray = self::toSentenses($text);
        $i = 0;
        $bigPiecesArray[0] = '';
        for ($k = 0; $k < count($sentArray); $k++) {
            $bigPiecesArray[$i] .= $sentArray[$k].self::$sentensesDelimiter;
            if (strlen($bigPiecesArray[$i]) > self::$symbolLimit){
                $i++;
                $bigPiecesArray[$i] = '';
            }
        }

        return $bigPiecesArray;
    }

    /**
     * Склеивание текста
     * @param array $bigPiecesArray - массив переведенных кусков текста, в произвольном порядке,
     * но ключи должна соответствовать исходному тексту
     * @return string - "склеенный" текст
     */
    public static function fromBigPieces (array $bigPiecesArray) {

        ksort($bigPiecesArray);

        return implode($bigPiecesArray);
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: Жесть, читать больно с такими грамматическими ошибками.

Comment: Вы о коде? Или тексте? А по существу?

Comment: @arashvg, Перефразируйте, пожалуйста, Ваш вопрос: исправьте грамматические ошибки, правильно расставьте запятые. Если ещё добавите побольше уточняющей информации, то Вы ускорите получение ответа.

Я реально прочитал только первый 3 предложения, потом стало обидно за русский язык, ну и дальше читать не стал.

Comment: Я бы поостерёгся считать каждую точку (даже с пробелом после неё) концом предложения. Контрпримеры: "Общая стоимость 1 руб. 25 к.", "Слово имеет т. Берия", "В Африке водятся слоны, бегемоты и т. д.". Ну и т. д.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Может я не туда копаю, может кто знает
> способ попроще?

**Есть, для таких вещей используется БД а в БД таблица в таблице есть 2 поля, одно из которых краткий текст статьи второе поле полная статья.**

Верхний кусок кода, вообще непонятен, т.к. в нем используются какие-то там еще переменные, которые не видно, и что и для чего они не понятно.

```
while ($pz < 1000) {
    $pz = $pz + strlen($pred[$i]);
        $abz[$l] = $abz[$l] . $pred[$i]; ///добавляю к блоку предложение
    }
```

Алгоритм такого рода действий строится иначе.

Берется текст. Обрезается до 1000 символов. Потом от конца данного текста обрезаем все до первой точки с конца. Конечно если 1 предложение не имеет в себе более 1000 символов, иначе такое не прокатит. :)

т.е.

> Существует метафорическое
> представление о тексте, как о
> лабиринте, в котором блуждают его
> читатели и исследователи, или
> спутанном клубке, который подлежит
> распутыванию. Не существует
> универсальной теории выхода из
> лабиринта или распутывания клубков,
> есть лишь некоторые эвристические
> принципы, которым бывает полезно
> следовать. Однако когда вы приступаете
> к распутыванию клубка, у вас заранее
> не может быть гарантий, что вы его
> сумеете распутать до конца; равным
> образом, не сумев его распутать, вы не
> имеете права утверждать, что этот
> клубок является нераспутываемым в
> принципе. Распутывание клубка
> производится извне, а разгадывание
> лабиринта изнутри. В тексте скрывается
> сам автор, текст - есть свидетельство
> о нём; каждое творение содержит в себе
> - в том или ином виде - образ своего творца.

обрезаем его

> Существует метафорическое
> представление о тексте, как о
> лабиринте, в котором блуждают его
> читатели и исследователи, или
> спутанном клубке, который подлежит
> распутыванию. Не существует
> универсальной теории выхода из
> лабиринта или распутывания клубков,
> есть лишь некоторые эвристические
> принципы, которым бывает полезно
> следовать. Однако когда вы приступаете
> к распутыванию клубка,

и далее косим до первой точки с конца

> Существует метафорическое
> представление о тексте, как о
> лабиринте, в котором блуждают его
> читатели и исследователи, или
> спутанном клубке, который подлежит
> распутыванию. Не существует
> универсальной теории выхода из
> лабиринта или распутывания клубков,
> есть лишь некоторые эвристические
> принципы, которым бывает полезно
> следовать.

Все. Но это опять же костыль, проще хранить в таблице нужный кусок текста(анонс)

ps

> разрыва в средине предложения.

так правильнее.

> В середине

Comment: дело в том, что как раз для того чтобы залитьв таблицу и нужно разбиение... есть текстовый файл с нескольками десятками статей, его нужно обработать и залить в БД... но перед етим нужно текст хоть както оформить... чтобы небыла сплошная каша...

За совет спасибо!

Comment: >етим

ЭТИМ первая буква "Э" :)

\+ нужно проверять на наличие многоточия "..." а иначе это 3 предложения будет по алгоритму. Ну и т.д.

Comment: Big_Text_Translate  - это кусок кода яндекса для перевода текста. что за бред...

@arashvg, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 0):

```html
function abzac($str){
$pred = explode('.', $str); 
$pz   = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < count($pred); $i++) {
  $lench   = strlen($pred[$i]);
  $pz = $pz + $lench;  
  if($pz > 400) {
   $abzac[]=implode('. ',$abz).'. ';
   $abz=array();
   $pz   = $lench;
  }  
  $abz[] = $pred[$i];  
 }
 return '<p>'.implode('</p><p>',$abzac).'</p>';
}
```